# Addroleassignment uses a subsite specific principal guid using Rest

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, roles, role-assignment

I am trying to add role assignments to SharePoint Online to a folder on a personal sub site.  I looked up all the users against the parent site and I have a guid of 282.  When I try and assign a new role assignment using 282 as the principal on my sub site I get `"Value does not fall within the expected range."`.  There are only approx 10 users that I can actually use to assign new role assignments and If I try and look up users on the parent site I cant create a role assignment for them as they are not listed on my sub site.
The URL I am using is:

```
  https://company.sharepoint.com/personal/me_company_com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('DOCUMENTS/TEST')/ListItemAllFields/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=70,roledefid=1073741826)
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Not a solution, however on further investigation I found that if I search for a user in the UI then that user gets added to the sub sites list of available users however assigned a new GUID relative to the sub site.